# Can't call map method in function with cats library

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I'm reading *Advanced Scala With Cats*. I stuck on this example at functor description (page 59):

```
object FunctorsDemo extends App {

  import cats.instances.function._
  import cats.syntax.functor._

  val func1 = (x: Int) => x.toDouble
  val func2 = (y: Double) => y * 2

  val func3 = func1.map(func2) // wrong line for me

}
```

In book everything is okay, but I have this exception:

```
Error:(10, 21) value map is not a member of Int => Double
  val func3 = func1.map(func2)
```

Can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have encountered a bug in Scala's type inference, the partial unification bug.

Add this to your `build.sbt`:

```
scalacOptions += "-Ypartial-unification"
```

There's a good writeup about it here if you're interested: https://gist.github.com/djspiewak/7a81a395c461fd3a09a6941d4cd040f2

Comment: Is it just a guess, or have you actually tested it? Even with `-Ypartial-unification`, it was throwing `diverging implicit expansion for type T
starting with method catsKernelCommutativeGroupForFunction1 in trait FunctionInstances` at me, for no apparent reason... A more complete verifiable example, with all the exact versions etc. would be nice.

Comment: I did test it in intellij, with `println(func3(10))`, which printed `20.0`.

Comment: Yeah! That helped me. Thank you!

Comment: Note that `-Ypartial-unification` will be enabled by default in Scala 2.13.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one configuration with the exact version numbers for which it works:

build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.typelevel" %% "cats-core" % "1.1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.12.5"
scalacOptions += "-Ypartial-unification"
```

Code (`FunctionIntDoubleFunctor.scala` in same directory as `build.sbt`):

```
object FunctionIntDoubleFunctor {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    import cats.syntax.functor._

    import cats.instances.function._

    val func1 = (x: Int) => x.toDouble
    val func2 = (y: Double) => y * 2


    val func3 = func1.map(func2)
    println(func3(21)) // prints 42.0
  }

}
```

Ammonite with `@ interp.configureCompiler(_.settings.YpartialUnification.value = true)` fails miserably on exactly the same code, and I don't know why, so maybe it has something to do with the tools you are using.